# Is my proof of the thought experiment that Walter Lewin proposed in lecture 16 valid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

> A tennis ball bounces off a wall elastically. The momentum of the wall changes, but the kinetic energy of the wall remains zero. How is that possible?

[Walter Lewin Lecture 16 - Ball bouncing on wall?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23745/walter-lewin-lecture-16-ball-bouncing-on-wall)

That proof made sense, but I didn't trust it 100%. The math seemed wonky at best.

Here's what I did:

Conservation of momentum states that

$$
m_{b}v_{b} = m_{b}v_{b}' + m_wv_w' \\ 
$$
because $v_b' = -v_b$,
$$
2m_bv_b = m_wv_w' \tag1
$$

While conservation of mechanical energy states that

$$
\frac{1}{2}m_bv_b^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_bv_b'^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_wv_w'^2
$$
When $v_b' = -v_b$,

$$
0 = m_wv_w'^2 \tag2
$$

I added equations (1) and (2), solved for $m_wv_w'$, then evaluated the limit
$$ \lim \limits_{v_w' \to 0} m_wv_w' = \lim \limits_{v_w' \to 0} \frac{2m_bv_b}{v_w + 1} = 2m_bv_b
$$

Does this adequately prove the situation?

Comment: I think you are correct, very nice. By the way a different way of phrasing the limit is that you are sending $v_w$ to zero and $m_w$ to infinity, keeping $p_w=m_w v_w$ fixed. Then the kinetic energy $p_w^2/2m_w$ vanishes in this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a perfectly elastic collision, you are heading in the right direction here. It looks like you're trying to say the thing your ball hits will have 2 times the ball's momentum. You might want to consider $2m_bv_bv'_w=m_w{v'_w}^{2}$ because it looks like something might've gone "wonky" when you added equation (1) and (2)